# Use avfoundation to recrod video and save it to photo gallery ~ Swift5

Tags: swift, video, avfoundation, avcapturevideodataoutput

My swift code below uses avfoundation to take a photo and place it on the imageview all in one class. I want to uses this code as a base and just when the uses calls func startVideo its recording and then when the user calls saveVideo func then it stops the recording and saves it into the imageivew.

[image]

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
var backCamera: AVCaptureDevice?
var frontCamera: AVCaptureDevice?
var currentCamera: AVCaptureDevice?
var photoOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput?

var cameraPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
var image: UIImage?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setupCaptureSession()
    setupDevice()
    setupInputOutput()
    setupPreviewLayer()
    startRunningCaptureSession()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

func setupCaptureSession () {
    captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo
}

 func setupDevice() {
    let deviceDiscoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: AVCaptureDevice.Position.unspecified)

    let devices = deviceDiscoverySession.devices

    for device in devices {
        if device.position == AVCaptureDevice.Position.back {
            backCamera = device
        } else if device.position == AVCaptureDevice.Position.front {
            frontCamera = device

        }
    }

    currentCamera = backCamera


}

func setupInputOutput() {
    do {
        let captureDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: currentCamera!)
        captureSession.addInput(captureDeviceInput)
        photoOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
        photoOutput?.setPreparedPhotoSettingsArray([AVCapturePhotoSettings(format: [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.jpeg])], completionHandler: nil)

        captureSession.addOutput(photoOutput!)

    } catch {
        print(error)
    }


}

func setupPreviewLayer () {

    cameraPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
    cameraPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
    cameraPreviewLayer?.connection?.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
    cameraPreviewLayer?.frame = self.view.frame
    self.view.layer.insertSublayer(cameraPreviewLayer!, at: 0)





}
func startRunningCaptureSession () {
    captureSession.startRunning()
}





@IBAction func startVideo(_ sender: Any) {

}


    @IBOutlet weak var photo: UIImageView!




    @IBAction func saveVideo(_ sender: Any) {


    }}

     extension ViewController: AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {
 func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
    //contains the photo variable
    if let imageData = photo.fileDataRepresentation() {
        print(imageData)
        image = UIImage(data: imageData)



    }

}}
```

Comment: In func cameraButton I want to start recording a video when called. Then when SaveButton is called I want the video stop recording and then be saved into the photo gallery in iPhone.

Comment: I don't know how to 1 take the video and 2 how to save it in the gallery. I changed my func's name

Comment: It does do some of the tasks it shows a live camera view on a view controller. That is import for what I am asking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can save record your video to file by creating and adding an `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` to your capture session, and making your `ViewController` conform to the `AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate`.

This example records 5 seconds of video to a file called "output.mov" in the app's Documents directory.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate {

    var captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    var sessionOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
    var movieOutput = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()
    var previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer()

    @IBOutlet var cameraView: UIView!

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        self.cameraView = self.view

        let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devicesWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
        for device in devices {
            if device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.Front{


                do{

                    let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device as! AVCaptureDevice)

                    if captureSession.canAddInput(input){

                        captureSession.addInput(input)
                        sessionOutput.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecJPEG]

                        if captureSession.canAddOutput(sessionOutput){

                            captureSession.addOutput(sessionOutput)

                            previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
                            previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
                            previewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait
                            cameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)

                            previewLayer.position = CGPoint(x: self.cameraView.frame.width / 2, y: self.cameraView.frame.height / 2)
                            previewLayer.bounds = cameraView.frame


                        }

                        captureSession.addOutput(movieOutput)

                        captureSession.startRunning()

                        let paths = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
                        let fileUrl = paths[0].URLByAppendingPathComponent("output.mov")
                        try? NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtURL(fileUrl)
                        movieOutput.startRecordingToOutputFileURL(fileUrl, recordingDelegate: self)

                        let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(5 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
                        dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                            print("stopping")
                            self.movieOutput.stopRecording()
                        }
                    }

                }
                catch{

                    print("Error")
                }

            }
        }

    }

    func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL outputFileURL: NSURL!, fromConnections connections: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) {
        print("FINISHED \(error)")
        // save video to camera roll
        if error == nil {
            UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(outputFileURL.path!, nil, nil, nil)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What build version is this in swift 3, 4.2 or 5?

Comment: @YaoSmith this is in 2 but you could download the Documents directory from the device in Xcode > Devices > iPhone > app name > Download Container. You can save the video to the camera roll by calling UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum() from the didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL delegate method.

Comment: I was able to convert most of the code to have non errors. However I have added a pic above with the errors. If you can just tell me what to write so I don't get errors. I will award you the bounty.

Comment: @YaoSmith There is an 'appendingPathComponent' method for type 'URL'
fixed by making sure it's a variable of type URL

`let documentURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
let fileURL = documentURL.appendingPathComponent("tempImage.jpg")` second error  You are calling the function with a string parameter, but the function does not take the string parameter.

Comment: What do I put on the second error? dispatch_time_t(DispatchTime.now()), Int64(5 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))). Dispatch_Time is causing the error.

Comment: dispatch_time_t is a UInt64. The dispatch_queue_t is actually type aliased to an NSObject, but you should just use your familiar GCD methods to get queues. The block is a Swift closure. Specifically, dispatch_block_t is defined as () -> Void, which is equivalent to () -> ().

Comment: So your stating that I have to put func setupCaptureSession from my original question into your answer.